# How to get user information from Visual Source Safe 2005 Administration?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

Is there any way to know user creation and modification date using Visual Source Safe 2005 administration? If not, then where can we get this information in server?

Answer (score 0):

No, Sourcesafe does not store this information anywhere.

if you lucky you can determine create date by looking at some "ini" file. I don't remember if each user gets its own "ini" file or not.